# what happens when a parent class object takes value of child class object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I was playing with code, see the comment besides the code, my question is:

Is og of child type or parent type?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    inherit og = new child();
    og.play();
    ( (child)og).kick((child)og);   //kick is a function in child class wi=hich accepts an object of the child class as parameter
    // gives an error if we remove explicit conversion
     System.out.println(og instanceof child);   //true
     System.out.println(og instanceof inherit);  //true
    System.out.println(og.getClass().getSimpleName());  //child
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's of `child` type, since you have instantiated `child` in this line

```
inherit og = new child();
```

and assigned the new `child` instance to `og`.

Comment: The OP is perhaps a bit unclear as to what they really want to know, but among the questions that follow from this interpretation would be "If `og` is of `child` type then why does one need to cast it in order to invoke its `kick()` method?"

Comment: @JohnBollinger since og is declared to be of inherit type, it's natural that it is referred to as such, even though, in reality it's of child type in this specific code example.

Comment: Without further qualification, that's oversimplified to the point of incorrectness.  The type of the *expression* `og` in the OP's code is (reference to) `inherit`.  That's not a question of what's "natural"; rather, it is specified by the language standard.  And that's why the casts are required.  That is also the type of the *variable* `og`.  That the object to which `og` refers has class `child` is another matter.

Comment: @JohnBollinger instanceof for child yields true. That means that it's of child type. It's not seen as such because of the declaration, which makes the casts necessary. But still, it's of child type. If you instantiate og as new inherit, then instanceof for child will yield false. Saying that something's "natural" effectively means that if you use your common sense, then you will see why that's the case. So I find your last comment to be unnecessarily nitpicking.

Comment: It's not nitpicking to say I disagree with your characterization.  In no way do I dispute that `og instanceof child` will evaluate to `true` in the OP's code.  What I am calling into question is whether that's relevant to what the OP wants to know.  This is the crux of the OP's lack of clarity, and it follows through to the question of which "it" you yourself are talking about.  There are the variable `og` and, if one chooses to distinguish, the expression `og`.  There is also the object to which `og` refers.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger to clarify, your disagreement is most welcome, but wen you pick the word "natural", which, in this context means "not counter-intuitive", then I will answer as in the comment above. Picking into the word "natural" was unnecessarily nitpicking. The other parts of your comments are not so. When someone asks me what an object's type is, I will "naturally" incline to focus on the type the object essentially is, yet, its declaration in this case refers to the superclass, which makes the cast necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry that you find my criticism of the term "natural" to be objectionable, but I hope that if you reread your comment then you will understand why I take it as conveying a message along the lines of "I see why you say that, but you're wrong."  In that light, I hope you also can accept that it is not my intention to nitpick your word choice, but rather to object to the "natural *but wrong*" assertion by establishing a more rigorous basis for my position than merely "natural".  Either way, I will say no more about that particular detail.

Answer (score 1):

The object "og" is of the child class. This process is known as polymorphism. Because the "child" class extends the "inherit" class, any commands done to the child class will also call on the parent's ("inherit") constructor.

When you say:

```
og instanceof child
og instanceof inherit
```

The reason why both of these say "true" is because you wrote "Inherit og = new Child();". So, the "Child()" causes the constructor in the "Inherit" class to be called. As a result "og" identifies as both of them.

The "child" is also calling the "inherit" constructor. So, both of these are true since both constructors are called. However, in reality the answer is that it's of type "child".

Comment: I don't disagree with the second and following sentences.  As for the first, however, the OP is perhaps a bit unclear as to what they really want to know, but among the questions that follow from this interpretation would be "If `og` is of `child` type then why does one need to cast it in order to invoke its `kick()` method?"

Answer (score 0):

> og is of child type or parent type?

As used in the example code, the fragment

> ```
> inherit og
> ```

declares `og` as a reference to an object of *type* `inherit`.  That is the type of the expression `og`.  This is a compile-time characteristic of the source code presented.  Thus, **`og` is of the parent type**.

The code presented also initializes variable `og` with a reference to an object of *class* `child`.  For all intents and purposes, that is a run time detail of an execution of the program.  It does not change the type of variable `og` or of the expression `og`, but it does mean that at run time, evaluation of the cast expression `(child) og` can be expected to succeed instead of throwing a `ClassCastException`.

A reference of a type **`T`** can refer to an object whose class is a subtype of **`T`**.  That does not change either the type of the reference or the class of the object -- these are different considerations.  I personally try to maintain the distinction by using the word choices you can see in this answer: references have a *type*, whereas objects have a *class*.

As a separate matter, please follow standard Java naming conventions.  In particular, classes should be named in camel case, *with an initial capital letter*.  Following that and the other standard conventions makes your code much easier for others to read.